# Can I auto-format Excel or Google Sheets cells containing times to include leading zeros for times less than 10 minutes or less than 1 minute?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm making a spreadsheet of Forza Horizon 5 Rivals times for my friends and I to use to compare our times easily. I'm trying to get it so that the race times we're entering end up in the format `[minutes]:[seconds].[milliseconds]`, with 2, 2, and 3 digits, respectively (for formatting consistency). If the time is less than a two-digit number of minutes, I want the [minutes] section to read "00", "01", "02", etc.

For example, if I enter a time of 48 seconds and 304 milliseconds, I want it to read `00:48.304`, and if I enter a time of 2 minutes, 13 seconds, and 696 milliseconds, I want it to read `02:13.696` whether or not the leading zeros are included

Using Google Sheets, I've been able to do the first example by using the custom number format `00:00.000`, but Excel won't accept that as a format... In both Excel and Sheets, I've also tried using the custom format `mm:ss.000`, but if I input the number from my first example, they input `1900-02-17  07:17:46` into the formula bar, and displays it as `17:45.600` instead of displaying as `00:48.304`

For the second example, I can't get it to work in Google Sheets, but it does seem to work in Excel. Sheets will display the correct time, but won't insert any leading zeros. Using either the `00:00.000` or `mm:ss.000` formatting, Sheets will display `2:13.696` unless the leading zero is entered manually. Using the `mm:ss.000` format, Excel will correctly display `02:13.696`

Sorry if there's already an answer to this somewhere, but if there is, I haven't been able to find it

I'm using Excel 2016, version 2205 and Google Sheets

Comment: Excel will accept the format `mm:ss.000`, but, even if you don't have hours in your time you **do** still need to specify a 0 for hours in your data entry, e.g. `0:2:13.696`

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I wake up later today. Thanks @SpectralInstance

Comment: what is your locale? share a spreadsheet instead of a screenshot! you will need a script when you enter48.304 without anay character as `:`

Comment: @MikeSteelson This is the spreadsheet as it sits on Google Sheets right now - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZWpnPFYXm4ecYIdrKecDj7poBEvJ4OpARhc0i0puIA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score -1):

This is not only a question of format. When you type 47.374 and transform it to minutes, you will find about 1136 hours (47 days). So you will have to detect if there is `:` and correct it by dividing by 24*60*60, the apply formatting

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(to_text(A1),"[:]"),A1*1,A1/60/60/24)
```